# Java hashcode without using the Object#hashCode method

Tags: java, hashcode

For an assignment I have to make a `HashTable` using double hashing, but for the hashing part I am not allowed to use `Object#hashCode()`, so I have to write my own.

So far I have the following code and I am looking for feedback if I am on the right track or if I should go for a different approach (see `hash` and `hash2` methods).

```
public class DoubleHashing<Key, Value> {

private int N;
private int M;
private Key[] keys;
private Value[] vals;

public DoubleHashing(final int capacity) {
    M = capacity;
    keys = (Key[]) new Object[M];
    vals = (Value[]) new Object[M];
}

public int hash(final Key key) {
    int hashKey = 0;
    if (key instanceof String) {
        final String k = (String) key;
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++) {
            int charCode = k.charAt(i);
            hashKey = ((hashKey * 27) + charCode) % M;
        }
    }
    return hashKey;
}

public int hash2(final Key key) {
    int hashKey = 0;
    if (key instanceof String) {
        final String k = (String) key;
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++) {
            int charCode = k.charAt(i);
            hashKey = 5 - ((hashKey * 27) + charCode) % 5;
        }
    }
    return hashKey;
}

public void put(final Key key, final Value val) {
    if (N == M) {
        System.err.println("Table is full");
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = hash(key); keys[i] != null; i = (i + 1) % M)
        if (keys[i].equals(key)) { vals[i] = val; return; }
    keys[i] = key;
    vals[i] = val;
    N++;
}

public Value get(final Key key) {
    for (int i = hash(key); keys[i] != null; i = (i + 1) % M)
        if (keys[i].equals(key))
            return vals[i];
    return null;
}

public int size() {
    return N;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use meaningful names for your fields:

```
private int N;
private int M;
```

What do those fields hold? What is the purpose of them?
Ask yourself those questions and use names that represent the meaning of your field:

```
private int size;
private int capacity;
```

### Don't cast where you don't need to:

```
keys = (Key[]) new Object[M];
vals = (Value[]) new Object[M];
```

This makes no sense; why do you cast a generic `Object[]` array to a `Key[]/Value[]` array?
Simply create them without casting:

```
keys = new Key[M];
vals = new Value[M];
```

### Your hashing methods don't return hashes

Your code is entirely broken in that regard. They only work for `String`s and you use them for getting your index. **This is not how hashing works!**
I don't know if this is a restriction of your assignment, but no matter how large the capacity of your table is, your hashing method should always return **the same** value in order to be comparable to other objects.

Comment: @GaintTree, yes, I had to rename my fields.

I cast because I cannot directly instantiate Type Parameters in my class, what makes me use the Object class. And yes, I have only made it to String to test. What would be another way to hash in an Universal way for all objects?

Comment: @KevinS `hashCode()` is the only common way to hash an object. If you only have to hash `String`s, then don't use parameters (`Key/Value`), but restrict your methods to only `String` objects. If you want to hash objects of various types, you have to write a hash function for each and every one of the different types you expect.